# How Can I Resolve an Assembly Conflict in a Legacy Silverlight / WCF Solution?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, silverlight

I recently took a legacy WCF project with Entity Framework 4 and upgraded it to EF6 and .NET 4.0. I took the legacy Silverlight client project and upgraded as well.  Problems started to arise when I added a new service reference to the upgraded WCF service. The code generated in the service reference has conflicts and will not compile.

My initial problem is that both Microsoft.Data.Services.Client and System.Data.Services.Client are part of the references…

> CS0433    The type 'EntitySetAttribute' exists in both
>   'Microsoft.Data.Services.Client, Version=5.6.4.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' and 'System.Data.Services.Client,
>   Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

This surprises me even more when I look at the generated code, References.cs, that fails. The usage is fully qualified.
`[global::System.Data.Services.Common.EntitySetAttribute("myTable")]`. Apparently both assemblies use the exact same namespace.

If I remove Microsoft.Data.Services.Client  I get:

> Error CS1061  'myEntities4' does not contain a definition for
>   'DefaultResolveType' and no extension method 'DefaultResolveType'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'myEntities' could be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

If I remove System.Data.Services.Client I get:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.Services.Client,
>   Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

This error is found in the XAML of a UserControl that uses a RadDataServiceDataSource.DataServiceContext.

I have spent quite a few hours trying several different paths including:

- Getting older versions of Microsoft.Data.Services.Client from NuGet.
- Using only one of the references, as mentioned above.
- Changing the references in the WCF service before adding the Service Reference in the client.
- Attempting advanced options when adding the Service Reference

  - Reuse all type from assemblies.
  - Reuse types in specified referenced assmeblies.

I have read the following posts, but they did not help:

[Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.dll vs System.Data.Services.Client.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773011/microsoft-data-services-client-dll-vs-system-data-services-client-dll)

[WCF error: Need to exclude all but one of the following types. Only matching types can be valid references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594253/wcf-error-need-to-exclude-all-but-one-of-the-following-types-only-matching-typ)

[Project does not build after updating a service reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082564/project-does-not-build-after-updating-a-service-reference)

I'm now considering building a new WCF and Web project to work around these issues. This should be an lengthy undertaking as well, and hopefully not a red herring.

Is this an artifact of upgrading from older versions of Silverlight, WCF, Entity Framework, or .NET in general? Please help me if you know what this is, or you have seen this before. A complete rewrite of the project to another platform is not an option unfortunately.

Comment: I don't know the specific answer, but try looking into **fuslogvw.exe** and assembly binding redirects.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code :

```
EFContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
EFContext.Configuration.LazyLoading = false;
```

Comment: Where do I put this code? In the generated service reference or in the service itself?

Comment: In service Code,when use get data form db.

Comment: Public class MyService{  [OperationContract]public Users[] GetUsers(){ var EFContext = new MyEntity(); EFContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
EFContext.Configuration.LazyLoading = false; var result=EFContext.Users.tolist(); return result; }